# Android deeplinking with navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on single activity app with navigation component. Implementing deeplinking now and I decided to give nav component deeplinking a try, it looks cool and easy in first sight.
I use ADB to produce deeplink with next code:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "ftnvegascp://login"
```

deeplinking worked as charm with "normal" manifest deeplinking. But now with nav component deeplinking. Here is my manifest activity code:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".presentation.main.NewMainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="feg.intent.action.vegas" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="${deeplink}" />
            <data android:host="account" />
        </intent-filter>

        <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
    </activity>
```

I also plan to remove "android.intent.action.VIEW" and scheme and host part from previous deeplinking after new deeplinking logic starts working.

This is nav_graph part with deeplink:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_bottom_2"
    android:name="fortuna.vegas.android.presentation.bottomnavigation.BottomFragment2"
    android:label="BottomFragment2">

<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/Logindeeplink"
    app:uri="ftnvegascp://login"/>
```

When I shoot the command in terminal for ADB I get this:

```
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=ftnvegascp://login flg=0x10000000 }
```

Where am I going wrong, this seemed pretty straight forward...

Comment: Does it work if you use `"ftnvegascp://login/"`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes it does! Can you explain me why? In the examples I looked before implementation there was no slash at the end. Also these deeplinks that I will use are defined by company that pays me and I can't add slash at the end.